# How to get data from form and add inputs to Mysql table.Using JQuery

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database

I'm trying to add input from HTML page to Mysql, I don't know what is wrong with my code. Why my input data from the form is not adding in MySQL database table? I already created a table in Mysql, but not able to insert values.

```
<form action="/data" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputName"> Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName" placeholder="Enter Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail">  Email Address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail" placeholder="Enter Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputcontactnumber">  Contact number</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="exampleInputcontactnumber" placeholder="Enter Contact number">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputRestaurantName"> Restaurant Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputRestaurantName" placeholder="Enter RestaurantName">
    </div>
    <div class="res mt-5 mb-5 text-center" >
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="startapp" class="btn btn-primary" ></a>
    </div>   
</form>
```

```
var express    = require('express');
var app        = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : '127.0.0.1',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'password',
    database :'mydb'

});
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/Register.html');

});

app.post('/data', function(req, res){

    connection.query(sql , function(err, result){
    var sql = "INSERT INTO customers (Name,Email,ContactNumber,RestaurantName) VALUES (" + req.body.exampleInputName + "', '"+req.body.exampleInputEmail +"','"+ req.body.exampleInputcontactnumber +"','"+ req.body.exampleInputRestaurantName +"')";
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("Data added");
    });

    res.send(data);

});

con.end();

app.listen(3000, function () {
console.log('App is running on port');
});
```

Comment: You have a INTO for a single column but you have value for 4  .. so youwant insert just one column or 4 columns ???

Comment: 4 column, I have added 4 columns Into the table

Answer (score 1):

In you query you have an insert for a single  column  but you have values for 4

you also miss the single quote at the begin of the values so if you want insert  a  single column you should  use

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO customers (Item)
 VALUES ('" + req.body.exampleInputName  +"')";
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("Data added");
    });
```

if you want insert value for 4 columns  you should

```
  var sql = "INSERT INTO customers (your_col_name, your_col_email, your_col_contact, your_col_resturant)
   VALUES ('" + req.body.exampleInputName + "', '"+req.body.exampleInputEmail +"','"+ req.body.exampleInputcontactnumber +"','"+ req.body.exampleInputRestaurantName +"')";
          if(err) throw err;
          console.log("Data added");
      });
```

Comment: Thank you , but it is not working it says /data was not found or deleted .

Comment: are you sure  ..  how you have this message with an insert statemnt .. ???   in which od the two query you have this message  ..  ???   . and where you execute the insert query  ??  in your code you just assign the sql code  .. but not execute  ..  probably you have some others error in others part of you code